# How to get facebook's inbox messages,contacts into our application

Tags: php, asp.net, facebook

I want php or asp.net code for fetching facebook's inbox messages and contacts into our application when the application is added into facebook

Answer (score 0):

For the contacts, use [friends_get](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/?u=facebook.jslib.FB.ApiClient.friends_get)

For messages, use [getThreadsInFolder](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Message.getThreadsInFolder)

Use the [official PHP library](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/PHP) to wrap it all together (the linked page has an example on getting friends list)

Note that some methods need extended permissions.